# How to validate Azure AD web form token in web service

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, azure-web-app-service

I have a WebForms project and a Web Service. In web forms i need to authenticate using AzureAD and take Token from this web site. This token need to pass to Web Service and web service need to validate this token

I got Token from Azure, but validation failing. it seems issue with sigingKeys

Default.aspx.cs Page_Load

```
            if (!Request.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Authentication.Challenge(
                   new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = "/" },
                   OpenIdConnectAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
            }
```

On startup.cs

```
 public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);

            app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());

            app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
            {
                ClientId = clientId,
                Authority = authority,
                RedirectUri = redirectUri,
                PostLogoutRedirectUri = redirectUri,
                Scope = "openid email profile offline_access " + scopes,
                TokenValidationParameters = new System.IdentityModel.Tokens.TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    ValidateIssuer = true,
                    ValidIssuer = tenant
                },

                // OpenIdConnect event handlers/callbacks.
                Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications
                {
                    AuthorizationCodeReceived = OnAuthorizationCodeReceived,
                    AuthenticationFailed = OnAuthenticationFailed
                }
            });
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Handle authorization codes by creating a token cache then requesting and storing an access token
        /// for the user.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="context"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        private Task OnAuthorizationCodeReceived(AuthorizationCodeReceivedNotification context)
        {
            return Task.Run(async () =>
            {
                string userId = context.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value;
                ConfidentialClientApplication cca = new ConfidentialClientApplication(
                    clientId, redirectUri, new ClientCredential(clientSecret), null, null);
                string[] scopes = this.scopes.Split(new char[] { ' ' });

                AuthenticationResult result = await cca.AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCodeAsync(context.Code, scopes);
                GenUtil.token = result.AccessToken;
                GenUtil.user = result.Account.Username.Split('@')[0];
            });
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Handle failed authentication requests by redirecting the user to the home page with an error in the query string.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="context"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        private Task OnAuthenticationFailed(AuthenticationFailedNotification<OpenIdConnectMessage, OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions> context)
        {
            context.HandleResponse();
            context.Response.Redirect("/?errormessage=" + context.Exception.Message);
            return Task.FromResult(0);
        }
```

On web service validate token

```
  try
                {
                    ConfigurationManager<OpenIdConnectConfiguration> configManager = new ConfigurationManager<OpenIdConnectConfiguration>(metaData, new System.Net.Http.HttpClient());
                    OpenIdConnectConfiguration config = configManager.GetConfigurationAsync().Result;
                    string tenant = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Tenant"];
                    TokenValidationParameters validationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                    {
                        ValidateAudience = false,
                        ValidateIssuer = false,
                        IssuerSigningKeys = config.SigningKeys, //.net core calls it "IssuerSigningKeys" and "SigningKeys"
                        ValidateLifetime = false
                    };
                    JwtSecurityTokenHandler tokendHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
                    SecurityToken jwt = null;
                    var result = tokendHandler.ValidateToken(GenUtil.token, validationParameters, out jwt);
                    Dictionary<string, object> valueColl = ((JwtSecurityToken)jwt).Payload;
                    if (valueColl["upn"].ToString().Split('@')[0].ToUpper() != GenUtil.user.ToUpper())
                    {
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {

                }
```

Web form should validate azure authentication and collect token from this. It should pass to Web service and it should validate the token and verify the token.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to validate access token in your web service, please refer to the following code:
On web service validate token

```
public JwtSecurityToken Validate(string token)
        {
            string stsDiscoveryEndpoint = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration";

            ConfigurationManager<OpenIdConnectConfiguration> configManager = new ConfigurationManager<OpenIdConnectConfiguration>(stsDiscoveryEndpoint, new OpenIdConnectConfigurationRetriever());

            OpenIdConnectConfiguration config = configManager.GetConfigurationAsync().Result;

            TokenValidationParameters validationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
            {
                ValidateAudience = false,
                ValidateIssuer = false,
                IssuerSigningKeys = config.SigningKeys,
                ValidateLifetime = false
            };

            JwtSecurityTokenHandler tokendHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();

            SecurityToken jwt;

            var result = tokendHandler.ValidateToken(token, validationParameters, out jwt);

            return jwt as JwtSecurityToken;
        }
```

On startup.cs

```
 public partial class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);

            app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());
            app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(
                new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
                {
                    // Sets the ClientId, authority, RedirectUr,ClientSecret as obtained from web.config
                    ClientId = clientId,
                    ClientSecret = clientSecret,
                    Authority = authority,
                    RedirectUri = redirectUri,
                    // PostLogoutRedirectUri is the page that users will be redirected to after sign-out. In this case, it is using the home page
                    PostLogoutRedirectUri = redirectUri,
                    Scope = OpenIdConnectScope.OpenIdProfile,
                    // ResponseType is set to request the id_token - which contains basic information about the signed-in user
                    ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.CodeIdToken,
                    // ValidateIssuer set to false to allow personal and work accounts from any organization to sign in to your application
                    // To only allow users from a single organizations, set ValidateIssuer to true and 'tenant' setting in web.config to the tenant name
                    // To allow users from only a list of specific organizations, set ValidateIssuer to true and use ValidIssuers parameter
                    TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
                    {
                        ValidateIssuer = false // This is a simplification
                    },
                    // OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications configures OWIN to send notification of failed authentications to OnAuthenticationFailed method
                    Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications
                    {
                        AuthenticationFailed = OnAuthenticationFailed,
                        AuthorizationCodeReceived = OnAuthorizationCodeReceived
                    }
                }
            ); ;
        }


        private Task OnAuthenticationFailed(AuthenticationFailedNotification<OpenIdConnectMessage, OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions> context)
        {
            context.HandleResponse();
            context.Response.Redirect("/?errormessage=" + context.Exception.Message);
            return Task.FromResult(0);
        }


        private async Task OnAuthorizationCodeReceived(AuthorizationCodeReceivedNotification notification)
        {
            var idClient = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder.Create(clientId)
                .WithRedirectUri(redirectUri)
                .WithClientSecret(clientSecret)
                .Build();

                string[] scopes = { };

                var result = await idClient.AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCode(
                    scopes, notification.Code).ExecuteAsync();

                var token = result.AccessToken;
        }
```

Package.config file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="Antlr" version="3.5.0.2" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="bootstrap" version="3.4.1" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="jQuery" version="3.3.1" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="jQuery.Validation" version="1.17.0" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc" version="5.2.7" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Razor" version="3.2.7" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization" version="1.1.3" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages" version="3.2.7" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform" version="2.0.0" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Identity.Client" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="Microsoft.IdentityModel.JsonWebTokens" version="5.3.0" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Logging" version="5.3.0" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols" version="5.3.0" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.OpenIdConnect" version="5.3.0" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens" version="5.3.0" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="Microsoft.jQuery.Unobtrusive.Validation" version="3.2.11" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin" version="4.0.1" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb" version="4.0.1" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Security" version="4.0.1" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies" version="4.0.1" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Security.OpenIdConnect" version="4.0.1" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure" version="1.0.0.0" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="Modernizr" version="2.8.3" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="11.0.1" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="Owin" version="1.0" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt" version="5.3.0" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="WebGrease" version="1.6.0" targetFramework="net472" />
</packages>
```

For more deatils, please refer to the [blog](https://www.jerriepelser.com/blog/manually-validating-rs256-jwt-dotnet/).

Comment: I am using custom redirect URL [http://localhost/COEManager/]. In that case what should be the stsDiscoveryEndpoint?

Comment: The stsDiscoveryEndpoint  has nothing to do with redirect url. I think you directly you use it

Comment: Can you please let me know the versions of each NuGet Package [In latest versions it is not working]

Comment: Is that you cannot start your application?

Comment: I am getting build error, so i modified some codes, but it is not working as expected.

Comment: IDX10501: Signature validation failed. Unable to match key:

Comment: Could you tell me which the version of Azure AD you use?

Comment: NuGet 5.5 OpenIDConnect I am using. Do you have any sample application? If I get a working application then easily I can integrate the changes to my application.

Comment: I am using NuGet 5.3 same as Package.config but still getting `IDX10501: Signature validation failed. Unable to match key:` error while validating Token

Comment: Could you please analyze your access token vai https://jwt.io/ and provide the information on the page?

Comment: It showing proper HEADER:ALGORITHM , PAYLOAD:DATA. But it showing  Invalid Signature in below

Comment: ```    <add key="ClientId" value="7879c3a4-4d66-48c8-988b-xxxxxxxx" />
    <add key="redirectUri" value="http://localhost:65338/" />
    <add key="stsDiscoveryEndpoint" value="https://login.microsoftonline.com/xxxx.onmicrosoft.com/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration" />
    <add key="ClientSecret" value="]:Al1X:XnVSejwT:pUDjrpgXukvOB631" />
    <add key="Tenant" value="xxxx.onmicrosoft.com" />
    <add key="Authority" value="https://login.microsoftonline.com/{0}" />
    <add key="Scopes" value="User.Read" />```
Please check the web config values, may something wrong.

Comment: Could you please share your project via GitHub? Besides, yoor web config file is right.

Comment: I have checked your code. I think it has no problem. Could you please share me the picture of the information you can see when you analyze your access token vai jwt.io ?

Comment: This project not working in IIS directly, can you please let me know what are changes required in web.config to support IIS [Http://localhost/AzureTest]

Comment: There is a Microsoft official sample(https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapi-manual-jwt-validation) to tell you how to manually validate a JWT access token. Please refer to it

Comment: @SijoyRajan Please refer to https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-identitymodel-extensions-for-dotnet/issues/1132